# GCP Compute Engine API Filter Issue with startTime and endTime in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spring-cloud-gcp, google-cloud-compute-engine

I'm working with the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Compute Engine API in Java and encountering an issue when trying to filter operations based on startTime and endTime within a specified time range. The code snippet I'm using is as follows:

```java
Compute compute = (Compute) GcpServiceClientUtility.getGoogleCloudServiceClient(GcpService.COMPUTE, credentialDetails);
assert compute != null;

// Fetch operations within the specified time range for a specific project
String filter = String.format("startTime eq %s",
        "2023-11-28T03:36:48.839-08:00");
OperationList operationList = compute.globalOperations().list(GcpConfigService.getKeyValueFromFile(credentialDetails, PROJECT_ID)).setFilter(filter).execute();
for (Operation operation : operationList.getItems()) {
    log.info(operation.getName() + ": " + operation.getTargetLink() + " " + operation.getOperationType());
}
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

`Invalid value for field 'filter': 'startTime ge \"2023-11-28T03:36:48Z\"'. Invalid list filter expression.`

It seems that the issue arises when trying to filter operations based on a time range using the `startTime` field. I've tried using the `ge` (greater than or equal) operator to specify a range but without success.

How can I properly filter operations in GCP Compute Engine API using `startTime` and `endTime` within a specific time range?